# SBT app with Spark and Cassandra - Symbol 'type <none>.package.DataFrame' is missing from the classpath

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra, sbt, datastax

I'm trying to create simple Apache Spark application that will connect to Cassandra using Datastax Cassandra connector  and do some operation and am getting error

`Symbol 'type <none>.package.DataFrame' is missing from the classpath.`

My `build.sbt`:

```
name := "spark-app"
version := "1.0"
scalaVersion := "2.11.11"


libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.datastax.spark" %% "spark-cassandra-connector" % "2.0.0",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.1.1" % "provided"
)

resolvers += "Spark Packages Repo" at "https://dl.bintray.com/spark-packages/maven"
```

My simple application:

```
package com.budgetbakers.be.dwh.spark
import com.datastax.spark.connector._
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}

object Distinct {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val conf = new SparkConf(true)
      .set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "127.0.0.1")

    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    println(sc.cassandraTable("ks", "users").select("gender").distinct().collect().mkString(","))
    sc.stop()
  }
}
```

when i try to `package` project i get following compilation error:

```
[error] /.../Distinct.scala:18: Symbol 'type <none>.package.DataFrame' is missing from the classpath.
[error] This symbol is required by 'value com.datastax.spark.connector.package.dataFrame'.
[error] Make sure that type DataFrame is in your classpath and check for conflicting dependencies with `-Ylog-classpath`.
[error] A full rebuild may help if 'package.class' was compiled against an incompatible version of <none>.package.
[error]     println(sc.cassandraTable("ks", "users").select("gender").distinct().collect().mkString(","))
[error]             ^
```

**Am I missing something? Maybe there is some dependency conflict?**

Versions of apps I use:

- cassandra: 3.1
- apache spark: 2.1.1
- spark cassandra connector: 2.0.0
- scala: 2.11
- sbt: 0.13.15
- sbt assembly plugin: 0.14.0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try adding the `spark-sql` dependency as well as the core library. For future reference there are example build files [here](https://github.com/datastax/SparkBuildExamples/blob/master/scala/sbt/oss/build.sbt)

Comment: Shouldn't it be a transitive dependency of the Cassandra Spark connector? Just curious. Given the OP does not use Spark SQL at all, I hardly understand why the dependency should be in the OP's `build.sbt`.

Comment: It's in the package implicts, by including the package._ it has to look up all the classes. Why it doesn't get pulled in automatically with the scc, I don't remember why that decision was made, perhaps to allow for multiple spark versions